# Better way to tokenize string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string of arbitrary characters. I would like to turn it into an array, where each character is in a single array element, EXCEPT of successive word-characters `(\w+)`, which should end up together in one array element. Example:

```
ab.:u/87z
```

should become

```
['ab','.',':','u','/','87z']
```

My first approach went like this:

```
mystring.split(/\b/)
```

Of course this groups together non-word characters:

```
['ab','.:','u','/','87','z']
```

I can take them apart in a subsequent step, but I'm looking for a more elegant way. Next I tried these:

```
mystring.split(/(\w+|\W)/)
mystring.split(/(\b|\W)/)
```

Both return nearly the desired result, only that they also return array elements containing empty strings, so I have to write something like

```
mystring.split(/(\b|\W)/).reject(&:empty?)
```

Now my question: Is there a simpler way to do this?

**UPDATE**: I made a silly mistake when I explained my example. Of course '87' and 'z' should be together, i.e. '87z'. I fixed my example.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. My mistake in providing the example. Fixed it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use split, use the scan method:

```
> "ab.:u/87z".scan(/\w+|\W/)
=> ["ab", ".", ":", "u", "/", "87z"]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
'ab.:u/87z'.scan(/\w+|./)    #=>["ab", ".", ":", "u", "/", "87z"]
```

I'm not exactly sure what you want because you said word-characters `(\w+)` but split the `87` and `z`. If I'm correct, `\w` should match letters, digits and underscores. Hence the `"87z"`.

```
'ab.:u/87z'.scan(/[A-Za-z]+|\d+|./)    #=>["ab", ".", ":", "u", "/", "87", "z"]
```

You could always do this to achieve what you showed there though

Comment: My mistake when writing the example. 87 and z should not be split, as you correctly point out.